# How can i see most popular requests with new relic?

Tags: newrelic

I installed new relic on my heroku app and it seems like I get a lot of information

I just wonder if it is possible to see simple stats like most popular pages?

Something like

```
mydomain.com/somepath  13 hits  
mydomain.com/somepath/deeper 3 hits  
mydomain.com/anotherpathe    26 hits
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in the Web Transactions page. There is a filter that shows you the highest throughput web transactions.

Hope that helps. If you want more detailed help, feel free to write support@newrelic.com (they're very nice :)